# Questionnaire items for capturing employees' performance

Tags: regression

I am having problems designing my instrument.

I am trying to model how financial and non-financial rewards (independent variables) are associated with employees' performance (dependent variable).

For the independent variables, I plan to capture this information with questions like:

1. The salary structure is competitive/attractive compare to its competitors
2. The currently offered bonuses are attractive for motivating employees
3. Awards really motivate me towards better performance, etc.

However, I am having a hard time to come up with any questionnaire item to capture employees' performance to get the data for dependent variable. I'd appreciate any examples or suggestions.

Comment: I kind of rewrote your whole question. Please double check if I have explained your question clearly. Also, it would be helpful if you can state **who** is filling in the questionnaire. The employers? Or the employees?

Answer (score 0):

I did only some short research and my suggestion could be only one starting point for further research out of many. I used to deal with the effect of transformational leadership on subordinate's task performance in one of my research projects. In the article of Shin-Guang Liang and Shu-Cheng Steve Chi (2012) Transformational Leadership and Follower Task Performance: The Role of Susceptibility to Positive Emotions and Follower Positive Emotions, J Bus Psychol the authors mention a seven-item measure developed by Wayne et al. (1997) The role of upward influence tactics in human resource decisions. Personnel Psychology, 50, 979-1006. The downside of this approach is probably that the question was answered by their respective supervisors.